# How to make passed in parameter optionally undefined in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have a declaration like the following that works, but I feel like there is a simpler way to do it.

```
function getData(
  slug: string | undefined = undefined
) {
```

I would have thought this would work but it gives me syntax errors

```
function getData(
  slug: string? = undefined
) {
```

Comment: the syntax is `getData(slug?: string) {}`, but you should be able to google this, or find it in the docs easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
function getData(
  slug?: string
) {
```

In this way you can call the function with `getData('something')` or `getData()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the parameter optional, not the type. Try:

```
function getData(
  slug?: string = undefined
) {
```